# Jpql join on multiple

Tags: java, hibernate, join, jpql

We have 2 entities: A and B.

A have a @OneToMany on a List.

Both entities have a date.

We want to get A entities that have date set to null and fill it with B that have a date set to null.

```
@Query("select a from A a " +
    "left join a.bs b " +
    "on b.date is null " +
    "where a.date is null")
```

We want to use a join because with the following request, if there is no B, no A will be displayed even if A has a date.

```
@Query("select a from A a where a.date is null and a.bs.date is null").
```

Here is data set to explain with an Example

```
A              B1              B2              Result
date not set   Date not set    Date not set    no result
date not set   Date not set    Date set        no result
date not set   Date set        Date not set    no result
date not set   Date set        Date set        no result

date set       Date not set    Date not set    A only
date set       Date set        Date not set    A with B1
date set       Date not set    Date set        A with B2
date set       Date set        Date set        A with B1 + B2
```

Example class:

```
public class A {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "bId")
    private List<B> bs;
}


public class B {
    @Id
    private Long id;
}
```

Thx a lot ! :)

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd query should simply be :

```
@Query("select a from A a where a.date is null and a.bs.date is null").
```

But it's weird, you example doesn't not correspond to you query... 
I would have written something like :

```
@Query("select a from A where a.date is not null and a.bs.date is not null")
```

Comment: Hi, thx for you response, your right for the request, I edit it, but for your response,
if a.bs.date is null and a.date is not null, then there will be no result.
But we need a result with an empty A.

In other words, i want this SQL query in JPQL:
SELECT * FROM A a
LEFT JOIN B b ON b.aId = a.id and b.date is null
where a.date is null.